# TIBCO EMS - Error in exporting schema - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.DataStoreConnectionCustomizer

Tags: tibco-ems

I am trying to use MySql for storing the TIBCO EMS 7.0 messages. Following is my configuration :-

**stores-db.conf**

```
[$sys.failsafe]type=dbstore
dbstore_driver_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Research
dbstore_driver_username=root
dbstore_driver_password=12345
```

**tibemsd-db.conf**

```
 dbstore_classpath      
 = ../../../../tibcojre/1.6.0/lib/ext/hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:../../../../t ibcojre/1.6.0/lib/ext/c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:../../bin/antlr-2.7.6.jar:../../bin/asm-a ttrs.jar:../../bin/asm.jar:../../bin/cglib-2.1.3.jar:../../bin/commons-collectio ns-2.1.1.jar:../../bin/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:../../bin/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:../.. /bin/ehcache-1.2.3.jar:../../bin/jta.jar:C:/temp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin .jar
```

dbstore_driver_name     = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dbstore_driver_dialect  = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jre_library             = C:/tibco/tibcojre/1.6.0/bin/server/jvm.dll

I made sure I could connect to MySql with the given user name and password and the files mentioned in the dbstore_classpath do exist in their specified paths.

When I try to export the schema to the database with the following :-

```
java -jar  c:\tibco\ems\7.0\bin\tibemsd_util.jar -tibemsdconf  c:\tibco\ems\7.0\samples\config\tibemsd-db.conf -createall  -export
```

I get the below error. Can somebody point me to a correct direction :-

> Apr 8, 2013 2:11:10 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry
>   getConnectionCustomizer WARNING: Could not create for find
>   ConnectionCustomizer with class name
>   'com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.DataStoreConnectionCustomizer'.
>   **> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.DataStoreConnectionCustomizer**
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.getConnectionCustomizer(C3P0Registry.java:193)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getConnectionCustomize
>   r(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:749)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createPooledConnection
>   Pool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:863)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConn
>   ectionPoolManager.java:331)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConn
>   ectionPoolManager.java:348)
>           at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoo
>   lBackedDataSource.java:140)
>           at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConne
>   ction(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:79)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProvi
>   derConnectionHelper.java:55)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
>           at com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.CreateStoreCallable.processStore(CreateSto
>   reCallable.java:329)
>           at com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.CreateStoreCallable.call(CreateStoreCallab
>   le.java:42)
>           at com.tibco.tibems.tibemsd.internal.db.CreateStoreCallable.call(CreateStoreCallab
>   le.java:33)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
>   va:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this issue. Adding here in case if needed.

Include `$EMS_HOME/bin/tibemsd_dbstore.jar` file to the **classpath**

```text
 jar -tvf tibemsd_dbstore.jar | grep DataStoreConnectionCustomizer
  1729 Sat Jul 28 11:32:34 PDT 2012 com/tibco/tibems/tibemsd/internal/db/DataStoreConnectionCustomizer.class
```